# What can be used as [context] in jQuery( expression, [context] )?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, get

The following code does not return anything:

```
$('.foo', $('<div class="foo">foo</div><div class="bar">bar</div>').get(0)).html()
```

Is there any way to specify a string representation of xml/html as the *context* parameter of the *jQuery* function?  I'm trying to select a section of an html document retrieved from an ajax request; the ajax callback (using `$.get()`, for example) provides the returned data -- in this case *html*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example is that your context is two sibling elements. Using a wrapper element will allow you to select things inside it. Notice the difference here:

```
$('.bar', $('<div class="foo"><div class="bar">bar</div></div>')).html(); // outputs "bar"
```